# Difference between "save location" and "public save location"

Tags: windows-10, windows-libraries

I am trying to move away from using the OneDrive as a default save location. In file explorer I right-clicked on Documents a pop-up appears that displays two library locations: the local C: drive and the OneDrive. My understanding is that "Set save location" will change the default save location such as when I click "save as" for any document.

If I change the "Set public save location", how is this different than the generic "Set save location" button immediately adjacent? What is the difference between these two settings?

Answer (score 0):

The Public Documents folder is accessible by any user account on the PC. 
Eg; if you want everyone to read your private stuff, put files in the Public Folder....